# How to calculate file size to pad in BitBake?

Tags: python, shell, yocto, bitbake, integer-arithmetic

I've written a `.bbappend` file to pad the generated image for `16-byte alignment`. However I can not write the padding logic in `bash` or `python` in `.bbappend` file, as it throws error.

Here's the fragment from the file:

```sh
# Anonymous python function to set the padding size variable
python () {
    d.setVar("TEE_SIZE", "0xac000")
}

do_deploy () {
    install -d ${DEPLOYDIR}
    ${TARGET_PREFIX}objcopy -O binary ${B}/core/tee.elf ${DEPLOYDIR}/tee_tmp.bin

    # Padding for 16 byte alignment
    bbnote "Padding to ${TEE_SIZE}"
    ${TARGET_PREFIX}objcopy -I binary -O binary --pad-to ${TEE_SIZE} --gap-fill=0x0 ${DEPLOYDIR}/tee_tmp.bin ${DEPLOYDIR}/tee.${PLATFORM_FLAVOR}.bin

    # Deleting temp TEE, after padding
    rm -f  ${DEPLOYDIR}/tee_tmp.bin
}
```

I would like to get the size of `${DEPLOYDIR}/tee_tmp.bin` and pad it to the next number divisible by `0x10`.

1. Can someone help me achieving this?
2. How can I perform arithmetic operations in `bitbake` file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: It was some syntax error

Comment: Can we actually have the log of the error? This will help much more than trying to guess what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

From what I have found, you cannot write arithmetic with Bash syntax in recipes written with shell syntax. What you can do is to let the application bc perform the arithmetic. If I have understood your problem correctly, you can do this to calculate the padding:

```
# Get the actual size of the file (readlink is only needed if the file might be a symlink)
TEE_SIZE=$(stat --printf="%s" $(readlink -f ${DEPLOYDIR}/tee_tmp.bin))

# Calculate padding
TEE_SIZE_PADDED=$(echo "n = $TEE_SIZE; if(n % 16 != 0) { n += (16 - n % 16)}; n" | bc)
bbnote "Padding to ${TEE_SIZE_PADDED}"

${TARGET_PREFIX}objcopy -I binary -O binary --pad-to ${TEE_SIZE_PADDED} --gap-fill=0 ${DEPLOYDIR}/tee_tmp.bin ${DEPLOYDIR}/tee.${PLATFORM_FLAVOR}.bin
```

Note that both `TEE_SIZE` and `TEE_SIZE_PADDED` are in decimal, not hexadecimal, but this should work fine with objcopy (although I have not tested it now).

Note that your recipe now depends on bc-native being installed in the sysroot, so you have to add something like this to your recipe:

```
do_install[depends] += "bc-native:do_populate_sysroot"
```